# What can cause high number of pending messages with no slow consumer?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I use ActiveMQ with Apache Camel.
Right now I'm experiencing this issue where in ActiveMQ there are high number of pending messages. The messages are stuck in pending state and the dequeue process is very slow.

[image: ActiveMQ web console]

But looks like it's not add up to much on dispatched count of each consumers.
[image]

Is my understanding correct that normally to have that much pending messages the size of dispatched queue of each consumers should already be nearer to the default prefetch limit (which is 1000)? But it's just 20-80 for each consumers?

I don't have much knowledge about ActiveMq. So where should I look to have any idea how to solve this issue?

**Connection Configuration**
01 is the active one, and 02 is in standby mode

```
failover:(tcp://mq01:61616,tcp://mq02:61616)
```

**Connection Factory**
First one is for most of the queues, the second one is dedicated to the task with lots of load.

```
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="my-connectionFactory" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="consumerPooledConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="2" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="my-connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: which acknowledgement mode are you using ??

Comment: I think your consumers did not send ACK messages, read this to understand these counters http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/What-is-the-meaning-about-quot-Pending-Queue-Size-quot-quot-Dispatched-Queue-Size-quot-quot-Dispatch-td2363533.html http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

Comment: @HassenBennour As far as I know, it's the default. No changes to acknowledge option.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a symptom of connections leak? I see codes where <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"> don't have 'destroy-method="stop"'

Comment: i think that closing the connection or not it is not the problem, yes maybe closing a connection will force the commit but this is not the problem. what your consumer deal with messages ? are you sure that your messages are treated and finished ?? i think that there is no commit some times

Comment: can you update your question with your configs, logs and code

Comment: have you tried with only 1 consumer

Comment: @HassenBennour updated. In the log (which is very messy), I just see that rate of messages receive from the queue is very slow.

Comment: can you post consumers code, update your ActiveMQConnectionFactory url with "?jms.optimizeAcknowledge=true" as explained here http://activemq.apache.org/optimized-acknowledgement.html

Answer (score 0):

I want to update that I have found that, in my case, the issue is because I have ActiveMQ's connection pool that is shared between both the ActiveMQ producer and consumer, and this somehow creates competition for available connections from the pool.

So the lesson learned is to always separate connection pool between producer and consumer.